# Are "How to..." questions for demos and try-this-at-home experiments on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not “home-experiment” questions?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/why-not-home-experiment-questions)

A point brought to my mind by [Evan's questions about shopping](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/268/520), is the place of demonstrations in our efforts here.

Demos are effective teaching tools and can be powerful attractors for getting people (potential students, potential funders, general enthusiasts...) interested in what we do, and they can be surprisingly tricky to build and operate without letting small corrections 
detract from the rhetorical impact we'd like them to have.

So are questions about the design, construction, care and operation of demonstration tools OK. I'll leave the question of acquisition of parts and/or whole apparatus to be discussed under Evan's topic.